# pushforward of cohomology via a projection

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $X,Y$ be two smooth closed manifolds and consider the projection $p:X\times Y\rightarrow Y$. I want to understand the pushforward
$$p_*:H^k(X\times Y,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H^k(Y,\mathbb{Z})$$
By our setting, we would like to use the Poincare duality (the idea c.f. [this anwer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/64755/479269))
$$H^k(X\times Y,\mathbb{Z})\cong H_{n+m-k}(X\times Y,\mathbb{Z})$$
where we assume $n=\dim{X}$ and $m=\dim{Y}$. But, with this idea, we will get a map
$$H^k(X\times Y,\mathbb{Z})\cong H_{n+m-k}(X\times Y,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H_{n+m-k}( Y,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H^{k-n}(Y,\mathbb{Z})$$
which is not what we expect (e.g. when $n=m$, this map is not so meaningful). So I want to know what is the correct way to define and understand such a map (must we use Thom-isomorphisms?).

Comment: You can do this construction for any map $f.$ This is what's known as the "Gysin map" associated to $f.$

Comment: @D. Brogan Thank you. I would like to know how to do it by Poincare duality as is mentioned in the link, because I focus on the closed manifolds case.

Comment: Oh I see. In general you don't get a map $H^k(X\times Y)\to H^k(Y),$ there is always an offset by the difference in dimension between $X\times Y$ and $Y.$ So your map will always look like $H^k(X\times Y)\to H^{k-n}(Y).$

Comment: @D. Brogan It seems that I need to go to see the Gysin map via the Thom isomorphism stuff to find what I want. Will I get a map in the same degree?